Is there a way to capture output variables from a flow when it exits unexpectedly
Is there a way to capture output variables from a flow when it exits unexpectedly, such as when the user navigates backward or closes the flow without completing it?
The issue I'm facing is that I am uploading files in the environment, and if users leave the flow unfinished, the files are created in Salesforce but the link between the document and the record is not created.
I am running the flow from an Aura component to link it to the "New" button of an object. I need a way to ensure that the output variables from the flow are captured even if the flow is exited unexpectedly, so I can maintain the link between the document and the record.
Any advice or solutions for this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I would say no, there is no way. You can detect the cancellation but I do not believe you can get data back. Perhaps flow reactivity can help you here, letting you have code react to the upload before the user does any navigation? Depends on whether the uploaded can provide an appropriate update.
